# Is there a command or way on how to retrieve or directly download a .csv file from raspberry pi to windows 7 using putty?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, raspberry-pi, csv

I am trying to remotely retrieve a .csv file from my raspberry pi using putty. Is that possible? If so, is there any command that allows me to automatically download or transfer that .csv to my windows pc? What command shall I run?

Answer (score 1):

Using putty? No.
But with some other tools, Yes.
Command line tool: PSCP.exe, you can download it from the same place as putty. Usage:

```
PSCP.exe user@server:/path/to/file c:\local\path\
```

Graphical tool: FileZilla
Just download it, run it, put in server address, username, password and port number, then hit `connect`, you'll be able to download any file you want from the server.